# Wamp doesn't see my httpdopcs folder

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I have wamp setup and it's working. The problem is I have all my site files in a folder called httpdocs and the server seems to not see it. For example

The server sees this address

```
http://localhost/mysite/test.php
```

But not this

```
http://localhost/mysite/httpdocs/test.php
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Do you get a 404 on `http://localhost/mysite/httpdocs/test.php`?

Comment: Where does your httpdocs folder live on you disc?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the contents of your httpdocs to a folder under c:\wamp\www